# C# - Convert HTML String to formated plain text

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, plaintext

Is there a way to convert a html string for example content saved using a wysiwyg editor such as `tinyMCE` to formatted plain text i.e. retain line breaks.

I've been looking at the HTML Agility Pack but there are no examples that show how you can achieve something like the above.

Basically I want send content saved using `tinyMCE` in an email notification but i need to ensure any styles and formatting saved by `tinyMCE` don't break the styles in my HTML email hence the need to convert the content to plain text.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not get it from the editor directly using `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' });` ?

Comment: @Adriani6 it removes line breaks and I'm saving to database and retrieving later to send in notification which runs as a background process.